# Directional derivative Multivariate

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the gradient, Hessian and the directional derivative of the following function at [1,1]
$$f(x)=x^T \left| \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2  \\
4 & 8 \end{array} \right|x + x^T \left| \begin{array}{c}
3  \\
4  \end{array} \right|+6.$$ 
Hello, please, my problem isn't about finding the gradient or the Hessian but how to simplify this function. Thanks.

Comment: Small notational quibble: it's a good idea to use parentheses () or brackets [] with matrices and vectors, instead of vertical bars (vertical bars sometimes indicate that you're taking a determinant).

Comment: Let $x^{T} = (x_1, x_2)$ and perform the matrix multiplication. $x$ will be the column vector. You'll end up with a quadratic in $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: thank u guys. So I'll have something like:
$f(x_1,X_2)=x_1^2+3x_1x_2+8x_2^2+3x_1+4x_2+6 $

Answer (score 1):

Actually, one does not need to rewrite $f(x)=x^TAx+x^Tb+c$ in order to find its Hessian or gradient. The linear and constant parts do not contribute to the Hessian. As for the quadratic term $x^TAx$, its Hessian matrix is nothing but $A+A^T$. This is a generalization of the one-variable formula $(ax^2+bx+c)''=2a$.

One can also keep the matrix notation when finding the gradient. Write $x=x_0+dx $ where $x_0=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. Then 
$$f(x)=f(x_0)+(dx)^TAx_0 + x_0^T A(dx) + (dx)^Tb +(dx)^TA(dx) \tag1$$
which implies 
$$\nabla f(x_0)= Ax_0+(x_0^TA)^T +b = (A+A^T)x_0 +b \tag2$$
This is a generalization of the one-variable formula $(ax^2+bx+c)'=2ax+b$.